# undefined php data using ajax

Tags: php, ajax

I am trying to send 2 values from cx_card to my getproduto.php. For this I am using ajax

The variable values:

com_id=1

cliente_id=3440

```
The form select:

<select width="200" name="produto" id="produto-list" class="produtoInputBox" onChange="getsubproduto(this.value);" <?php echo $permissao; ?>>
```

ajax code

```
function getproduto(val,val_id) {
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "inc/cx/get_produto.php",
data:'com_id='+val+'&cliente='+val_id,
success: function(data){
  $("#produto-list").html(data);

  }
 });
}
```

My Query in getproduto.php

```
$query ="SELECT * FROM apolices WHERE id_cliente='".$_POST['cliente_id']
        ."' and id_companhia = '".$_POST['com_id']."'";
$results = $db_handle->runQuery($query);
```

In cx_card i have print the query i have recibe from getproduto.php the result is:

```
SELECT * FORM apolices WHERE id_cliente='undefined' and id_companhia='1'
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What did you expect? You're only passing in one argument, `val` and using that for both arguments in data. If you want two different values then pass in two arguments to getproduto.

Comment: **Danger**: You are **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that you need to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: If you have 2 variables on php why do you have only 1 in jquery ?

Comment: Quentin this website is  only allowed for 10 people acess in the work thanks for the warning

Answer (score 1):

You're only passing one argument to your `getproduto` function. If you want two different values you need two different arguments. Try this:

```
function getproduto(com_id, cliente_id) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "inc/cx/get_produto.php",
        data:'com_id='+com_id+'&cliente_id='+cliente_id,
        success: function(data){
            $("#produto-list").html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: result: SELECT FROM apolices WHERE id_cliente='undefined' and id_companhia='1'

Comment: Add the code that calls `getproduto` to your question. You might have added a second argument to `getproduto` but are you passing both in?

Comment: <select  width="200" name="produto"  id="produto-list" class="produtoInputBox"  onChange="getsubproduto(this.value);"  <?php echo $permissao; ?>> this calls the function and the functions call the getproduto.php

Comment: I said add it to your question above... It's difficult to read in a comment. Also that's calling `getsubproduto`, not `getproduto`.

Comment: thanks styphon, i have add  and  i have change the name

Answer (score 1):

You're only sending in one value:

```
function getproduto(val) {
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "inc/cx/get_produto.php",
    data:'com_id='+val+'&cliente_id='+val,
    success: function(data){
    $("#produto-list").html(data);

   }
  });
}
```

You should be sending two:

```
function getproduto(val,val_id) {
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "inc/cx/get_produto.php",
    data:'com_id='+val+'&cliente_id='+val_id,
    success: function(data){
    $("#produto-list").html(data);

   }
  });
}
```

Comment: result:  SELECT FROM apolices WHERE id_cliente='undefined' and id_companhia='1'

Comment: Of course it's undefined if you don't give it a value.  That's the whole problem.  You are specifying that you HAVE a client_id, but you're not passing it in.  Pass it in.

Comment: i have on cx_card $cliente['id']=$valores_cliente['id'];